# Add custom field in onepage check out,order,invoice,sales

Tags: module, onepage-checkout, ce-1.9.1.0, invoice, custom

I am new in Magento development I have created the custom module to insert field MOBILE in Customer Account Registration form [image: field is mobile]

but
(1) now I want to add this field in everywhere like one-page checkout, order page, sales page, shipping page, invoice detail page..likewise...so it is possible in my one custom module??
(2)  or should I create this functionality in one module or i have to create the different module for each other any help should be appreciable?

Comment: i have create custom field following this article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11501020/magento-add-a-field-on-default-registration-form

Answer (score 2):

You can add this field everywhere it's needed (as you mentioned checkout, order page, sales page,...) etc. within **one** module.

A module named `Vendor_MobileNumber` or even better `Vendor_CustomFields` (or similar) (where `Vendor` is your vendor/company name) could be handy so that you can extend it later for additional fields.